# How to handle two jsp forms pages in Spring MVC controller class

Tags: spring, forms

I have two different jsp pages one is login.jsp and form.jsp.i want to build application like ones login success then form page will open. here i am handle two jsp pages but it will show ambiguity problem.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String loginModel(Model model){

    model.addAttribute("loginBean",new LoginBean());
    return "login";
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String model(Model model){

    //FrontBean fBean=new FrontBean();
    model.addAttribute("frontBean",new FrontBean());


    return "form";
}
```

Comment: Please edit your title and add some informations about your issue (What's the problem )

Comment: please suggest how to map two jsp pages

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is your login page, it is your welcome page also

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String loginModel(Model model) {

    model.addAttribute("loginBean", new LoginBean());
    return "login";
}
```

then you should not add the same path to another method. change your other method to like this (change the mapping value to the second method)

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/welcome", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String model(Model model){

    //FrontBean fBean=new FrontBean();
    model.addAttribute("frontBean",new FrontBean());


    return "form";
}
```

You also need business logic to check the username and password. thereafter redirect to your welcome page like this. (your **login.jsp** should send the username and password to **/check-user** in post method)

```
@PostMapping("/check-user")
String checkUser(@RequestParam("userName") String userName , @RequestParam("passWord") String passWord){
    if(userName.equals("Your username") && passWord.equals("Your password")){
        return "redirect:welcome";
    }
    return "error";
}
```

*Remember this is not a secure way to implement. it is just an example of an easy understanding. you can implement your own things. best of luck*